# SQL Server view not working after edit in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, view, ssms

I had a view that worked, I edited it in SQL Server Mgmt Studio, it didn't work, I took out the changes and saved it down, it still doesn't work despite reverting it back to its original state.

I'm getting the error

> Joined tables cannot be specified in a query containing outer join
>   operators. View or function 'adept_invoiced' contains joined tables.

I've googled around and come up with a possible join syntax problem due to the view being written in 2001 and me trying to edit it (for the first time) in Management Studio.

The view ran perfectly for years until I edited it this morning.

This is the From/Where section....

```
FROM   dbo.SYS_COMP_ADDRESS
       CROSS JOIN dbo.SL_ACCOUNTS
       INNER JOIN dbo.SL_TRANSACTIONS
                  INNER JOIN dbo.ORD_HEADER
                    ON dbo.SL_TRANSACTIONS.ST_ORDER_NUMBER =
                       dbo.ORD_HEADER.OH_ORDER_NUMBER
                  INNER JOIN dbo.SL_PL_NL_DETAIL
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.STK_STOCK
                               ON dbo.SL_PL_NL_DETAIL.DET_STOCK_CODE =
                                  dbo.STK_STOCK.STKCODE
                             INNER JOIN dbo.ORD_DETAIL
                               ON dbo.SL_PL_NL_DETAIL.DET_ORDER_LINK =
                                  dbo.ORD_DETAIL.OD_PRIMARY
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.STK_STOCK3
                               ON dbo.SL_PL_NL_DETAIL.DET_STOCK_CODE =
                                  dbo.STK_STOCK3.STKCODE3
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.STK_STOCK_2
                               ON dbo.SL_PL_NL_DETAIL.DET_STOCK_CODE =
                                  dbo.STK_STOCK_2.STKCODE2
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PRC_PRICE_RECS2
                               ON dbo.SL_PL_NL_DETAIL.DET_PRICE_CODE =
                                  dbo.PRC_PRICE_RECS2.PRCODE2
                    ON dbo.SL_TRANSACTIONS.ST_HEADER_KEY =
                       dbo.SL_PL_NL_DETAIL.DET_HEADER_KEY
         ON dbo.SL_ACCOUNTS.CUCODE = dbo.SL_TRANSACTIONS.ST_COPYCUST
       INNER JOIN dbo.SL_ACCOUNTS2
         ON dbo.SL_ACCOUNTS.CUCODE = dbo.SL_ACCOUNTS2.CUCODE2
WHERE  ( dbo.SL_TRANSACTIONS.ST_TRANTYPE IN ( 'INV', 'CRN' ) )
       AND ( dbo.SL_TRANSACTIONS.ST_BATCH_FLAG <> 1 )
       AND ( dbo.SL_ACCOUNTS.CUCODE <> '1023134' )
       AND ( dbo.SL_ACCOUNTS.CUCODE <> '1023265' )
       AND ( dbo.SL_ACCOUNTS.CUSORT NOT LIKE '%other income%' )
       AND ( dbo.SL_ACCOUNTS.CUSORT NOT LIKE '%supplier%' )
```

I'm not sure where it might be failing, or how to fix it!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1 just because I've never heard of that error! You have 3 consecutive `JOIN` conditions right down under the final `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is this intentional? Unless you can tell us what the semantics are supposed to be we can't tell you the correct syntax though.

Comment: Where are you getting this error from? It doesn't sound like a SQL Server error, so presumably it's not coming directly from querying the view in SSMS?

Comment: @Damien Msg 4424 `select * from sys.messages where text like '%Joined tables cannot be specified%'`

Comment: I suggest in the future that you don't edit the view this way - in 2008+ versions of Management Studio you can choose `modify` instead, and this just lets you work with the view code in a normal query window, without any of the SSMS "helper" functionality, baggage, and bugs that go along with it...

Comment: I've discovered that the problem only happens when I access this View from a View that uses Union All to draw the same info from multiple identical databases.

Comment: I've managed to get back to square one by restoring a backup and copying the views over. Well that's a whole day wasted! Bring back Enterprise Manager!! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
FROM   dbo.SYS_COMP_ADDRESS 
       CROSS JOIN dbo.SL_ACCOUNTS 
       INNER JOIN dbo.SL_TRANSACTIONS 
                  INNER JOIN dbo.ORD_HEADER 
                    ON dbo.SL_TRANSACTIONS.ST_ORDER_NUMBER = 
                       dbo.ORD_HEADER.OH_ORDER_NUMBER 
                  INNER JOIN dbo.SL_PL_NL_DETAIL
                    ON dbo.SL_TRANSACTIONS.ST_HEADER_KEY = 
                       dbo.SL_PL_NL_DETAIL.DET_HEADER_KEY 
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.STK_STOCK 
                               ON dbo.SL_PL_NL_DETAIL.DET_STOCK_CODE = 
                                  dbo.STK_STOCK.STKCODE 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.ORD_DETAIL 
                               ON dbo.SL_PL_NL_DETAIL.DET_ORDER_LINK = 
                                  dbo.ORD_DETAIL.OD_PRIMARY 
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.STK_STOCK3 
                               ON dbo.SL_PL_NL_DETAIL.DET_STOCK_CODE = 
                                  dbo.STK_STOCK3.STKCODE3 
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.STK_STOCK_2 
                               ON dbo.SL_PL_NL_DETAIL.DET_STOCK_CODE = 
                                  dbo.STK_STOCK_2.STKCODE2 
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PRC_PRICE_RECS2 
                               ON dbo.SL_PL_NL_DETAIL.DET_PRICE_CODE = 
                                  dbo.PRC_PRICE_RECS2.PRCODE2 
         ON dbo.SL_ACCOUNTS.CUCODE = dbo.SL_TRANSACTIONS.ST_COPYCUST 
       INNER JOIN dbo.SL_ACCOUNTS2 
         ON dbo.SL_ACCOUNTS.CUCODE = dbo.SL_ACCOUNTS2.CUCODE2 
WHERE  ( dbo.SL_TRANSACTIONS.ST_TRANTYPE IN ( 'INV', 'CRN' ) ) 
       AND ( dbo.SL_TRANSACTIONS.ST_BATCH_FLAG <> 1 ) 
       AND ( dbo.SL_ACCOUNTS.CUCODE <> '1023134' ) 
       AND ( dbo.SL_ACCOUNTS.CUCODE <> '1023265' ) 
       AND ( dbo.SL_ACCOUNTS.CUSORT NOT LIKE '%other income%' ) 
       AND ( dbo.SL_ACCOUNTS.CUSORT NOT LIKE '%supplier%' )
```

Comment: Moving the `ON` clause around changes the semantics of the query.

Comment: that's seems to work, thanks. Although I'm still getting a similar error when accessing that view from another view that uses Unions to join the same views from different databases.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the old style join syntax anywhere so search for `*=` and `=*` in your view definition

Comment: I'm only using '=' in case statements.....i'd post the whole script, but its very long!

Comment: My post seems to have had the asterisk stripped out(*=, =*)

Comment: @SPE109 - Content in `*` is *italicised* or in `**` is **bolded**. Surround it with backticks to get it treated as code.